# SQL Oracle---get last record for every month

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a table that contain some Inspection Data. Every commodity needs to be inspected every month. The goal here is to find the last inspected record for each month.

*Table Inspection:*

**INSPECTION_I--------INSPECTION_TS**

200--------------------------- 10/20/2011

201----------------------------10/24/2011

202----------------------------10/26/2011

Table Product_Inspection:

**INSPECTION_I------------------ASSET_I**

200------------------------------------1000

201------------------------------------2000

Table Box_Inspection

**INSPECTION_I--------ASSET_I**

202------------------------3000

*Table Product*

**ASSET_I------------ASSOCIATED_BOX_ASSET_I**

1000---------------------------3000

*Table BOX:*

**ASSET_I------------OTHER_STUFF**

3000--------------------#####

Now in this case what I want is **201** and not **200**. I tried to do **MAX(to_char(inspection_ts, 'mm/yyyy'))** but that  is not helping. There is one more issue. For some reason, I keep getting the Cartesian in a case where a Product or a Box is inspected twice or more in a month. All I want is one inspection every month and it should be the last inspection for each month. I am really close to getting it but if someone can help, I would really appreciate it. I was able to get it done through a nested cursor but I don't want that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to use analytic functions to do this kind of query.  Something like:

```
with data as
(
    select 1 product_id, 100 inspection_id, to_date('09/04/2011', 'MM/DD/YYYY') inspection_date from dual union all
    select 1 product_id, 101 inspection_id, to_date('09/14/2011', 'MM/DD/YYYY') inspection_date from dual union all
    select 1 product_id, 103 inspection_id, to_date('10/04/2011', 'MM/DD/YYYY') inspection_date from dual union all
    select 1 product_id, 105 inspection_id, to_date('11/01/2011', 'MM/DD/YYYY') inspection_date from dual union all
    select 2 product_id, 102 inspection_id, to_date('09/24/2011', 'MM/DD/YYYY') inspection_date from dual union all
    select 2 product_id, 104 inspection_id, to_date('10/05/2011', 'MM/DD/YYYY') inspection_date from dual
)
select *
from 
(
    select
        product_id,
        inspection_id,
        inspection_date,
        row_number() over (
            partition by
                product_id,
                trunc(inspection_date, 'MM') -- Month
            order by
                inspection_date desc
        ) rn
    from
        data
)
where rn = 1 -- indicates last inspection date of the month for each product
```

Comment: Hey Craig, I haven't worked with Analytic Functions but it seems its definitely something to look at. Just to let you know, I am also getting a input parameter in my SP and returning one cursor that I am fetching in the Java DAO layer. Therefore, its a dynamic SQL String. If I go this route, would this integrate with my current SP?

Comment: Yeah, this should be able to work for your SP, assuming you are in at least 9i.  If you have any questions about how to get it to work, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

use a subquery

```
Select [ColName List]
From TableName a
Where DateTimeColumname 
   = (Select Max(DateTimeColumnName)
      From TableName 
      Where DateTimeColumnName < 1+Last_Day(a.DateTimeColumnName))
```